# TSQL Sum aggregating multiple columns with a group by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate

Hi have three tables as part of a much larger query and I am trying to aggregate some of the values for a calculation but the result is doubling as the sum aggregate is totaling all rows before the group by occurs.

**Tables:**

*SR01*

```
select * from sr01 where ReportKey = 109626
```

[image]

*AC95*

```
select * from ac95 where ReportKey = 109626
```

[image]

*AC96*

```
select * from ac96 where ReportKey = 109626
```

[image]

Note the 2 rows in this case

**Query**

```
SELECT 'Month' AS [Period],
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionCode,'') AS RegionCode,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionName,'') AS RegionName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    SR01.ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(LCRep.RepName,'') AS RepName,
    AC95.PrepTime, AC95.SvcPrepTime , AC95.TravelTime , AC95.SvcTravelTime , AC95.VisitTime , AC95.SvcVisitTime,
    SUM(AC95.PrepTime + AC95.SvcPrepTime + AC95.TravelTime + AC95.SvcTravelTime + AC95.VisitTime + AC95.SvcVisitTime) AS HoursMonth,
    SR01.ReportKEy
FROM dbo.SR01
    INNER JOIN AC95 ON AC95.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    INNER JOIN AC96 ON AC96.ReportKey = AC95.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestsNonReportView ON RequestsNonReportView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LCRep ON SR01.ServicingRep = LCRep.RepID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch ON SR01.ServicingBranch = Branch.BranchID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Region ON Region.RegionCode = Branch.Region
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Zone ON Zone.ZoneAbbrev = Region.Zone 
WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
    AND SR01.[Status]='X'
    AND SR01.RequestType <> 'MN' 
    AND SR01.DateComplete BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateTo), 0) AND @DateTo
    AND (AC95.OnOffSite = 'ON' OR AC95.OnOffSiteSvc = 'ON')
    AND SR01.ServicingRep = @ServicingRep
GROUP BY Zone.ZoneID, Zone.ZoneName, Region.RegionCode, Region.RegionName, Branch.BranchID, BranchName, SR01.ServicingRep, LCRep.RepName, SR01.ReportKEy,AC95.PrepTime,AC95.SvcPrepTime , AC95.TravelTime , AC95.SvcTravelTime , AC95.VisitTime , AC95.SvcVisitTime
```

*Result*

Note that the values PrepTim, TravelTime and VisitTime are not aggregated and appear correctly. When using the SUM aggregate to add them the total is double what was expected at 11 rather than 5.5.

[image]

Thinking that this was probably due to the multiple rows in AC96 I removed the Group By and there are two rows shown. This must be why the SUM aggreagte is doubling the value.

[image]

**Question**

How do I correctly term the query to SUM the values correctly without it doubling, or more, the number when there are multiple rows in AC96?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
;WITH cte_PreResult AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT 'Month' AS [Period],
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionCode,'') AS RegionCode,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionName,'') AS RegionName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    SR01.ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(LCRep.RepName,'') AS RepName,
    AC95.PrepTime, 
    AC95.SvcPrepTime, 
    AC95.TravelTime, 
    AC95.SvcTravelTime, 
    AC95.VisitTime, 
    AC95.SvcVisitTime,
    SR01.ReportKEy
FROM dbo.SR01
INNER JOIN AC95 
    ON AC95.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
INNER JOIN AC96 
    ON AC96.ReportKey = AC95.ReportKey
LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestsNonReportView 
    ON RequestsNonReportView.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey 
LEFT JOIN dbo.LCRep 
    ON SR01.ServicingRep = LCRep.RepID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Branch 
    ON SR01.ServicingBranch = Branch.BranchID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Region 
    ON Region.RegionCode = Branch.Region
LEFT JOIN dbo.Zone 
    ON Zone.ZoneAbbrev = Region.Zone 
WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
    AND SR01.[Status]='X'
    AND SR01.RequestType <> 'MN' 
    AND SR01.DateComplete BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateTo), 0) AND @DateTo
    AND (AC95.OnOffSite = 'ON' OR AC95.OnOffSiteSvc = 'ON')
    AND SR01.ServicingRep = @ServicingRep
)

SELECT  [Period],
        ZoneID,
        ZoneName,
        RegionCode,
        RegionName,
        BranchID,
        BranchName,
        ServicingRep,
        RepName,
        SUM(AC95.PrepTime + AC95.SvcPrepTime + AC95.TravelTime + AC95.SvcTravelTime + AC95.VisitTime + AC95.SvcVisitTime) AS HoursMonth,
        ReportKey
FROM cte_PreResult
GROUP BY [Period],
        ZoneID,
        ZoneName,
        RegionCode,
        RegionName,
        BranchID,
        BranchName,
        ServicingRep,
        RepName,
        ReportKey
```

Comment: While that works I was looking to do this within the main query body as this is an extract from a larger query. Is that possible.

Comment: Sure just add District
SUM(DISTINCT AC95.PrepTime + AC95.SvcPrepTime + AC95.TravelTime + AC95.SvcTravelTime + AC95.VisitTime + AC95.SvcVisitTime) AS HoursMonth,